# Large scale objects - wiggling vertices (Blender 2.79b)

Tags: modeling, objects

I am working on this large landscape scene and I noticed an issue with objects vertices. When I move around the scene the vertices wobble and the edges are never straight. The problem isn't so much with the scale of the objects but where the origin  is.

Because I imported the objects from Autocad, the orgin is something like 400km away from the actual object.

When I move the origin to centre of mass, the vertices stop wobbling, but the edges freeze in the deformed positions (not straight)

Does anyone have a solution to this please?

[image]

Comment: I think you should scale down your scene. large numbers are known to lose accuracy.